# Sharepoint Field or property "Body" does not exist ServerException

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, com

I am trying to programatically insert a discussion post into a Sharepoint discussion board list using the client object model in C#. I am using the following code:

```
 
var discussionList = sharepointContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Discussion");

    var discussionItem = Utility.CreateNewDiscussion(sharepointContext,  discussionList, "Test");

                discussionItem["Body"           ]    = "Hello world!"
                discussionItem["Author"         ]    = 22;
                discussionItem["Editor"         ]    = 22;
                sharepointContext.Load(discussionItem);
                discussionItem.Update();
                sharepointContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

However, whenever I run it, I get this exception

```
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException was unhandled
      Message=Field or property "Body" does not exist.
      Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
      ServerErrorCode=-1"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you remove the two lines starting `sharepointContext`? (Or rather, on exactly which line do you get that exception?)

Comment: The error comes from the line sharepointContext.ExecuteQuery(). If I remove the two lines above it, no exception is thrown, but it doesn't add the post to the site either.

Comment: Fair enough. I wondered about those lines because I'm not too familiar with the client OM.

Comment: Fixed it. I'll post my solution as soon as stackoverflow lets me (I don't have enough points, so I have to wait 8 hours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the code in the question didn't work is because you called `Update()` *after* calling `SPContext.Load()`. If you call `Update()` first, you'll be fine.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I don't know why I didn't try that. Thanks!

Comment: Had the exact same issue. Thanks!